# Factorization in a proof of induction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction, factoring

I have to prove the following:

$1+3^3+ ... + (2n+1)^3=(n+1)^2(2n^2+4n+1)$ by induction.

**My try:**

Base case, $n=1$:

$1+3^3=(2)^2(2\cdot1^2 + 4\cdot1 + 1)$, which is true.

By inductive hypothesis, assume $n=k$:

$1 + 3^3 + ... + (2k+1)^3=(k+1)^2 (2k^2 + 4k + 1)$

For $n=k+1$

$1 + 3^3 + ... + (2k+1)^3 + (2k+3)^3 = (k+2)^2 ( 2(k+1)^2 + 4(k+1) + 1)$

Using the inductive hypothesis we need to prove that

$(k+1)^2(2k^2+4k+1) + (2k+3)^3= (k+2)^2 ( 2(k+1)^2 + 4(k+1) + 1)$

and here I have the problem, because I don't know how to manipulate any of the sides of the equation to prove this. I tried in both sides but I can't find the way. One of my last attempts ended here:

$(k+1)^2(2k^2+4k+1) + (2k+3)^3= (k+2)^2 ( 2(k+1)(k+3) + 1 )$

Which is true by wolfram alpha.

PS: I'm aware that there are a lot of papers and information about this proof but I'm not searching another way or something like that, because I saw a lot of posts about proving this statement via induction, but all of them used the last  term as (2n-1)^3, and I need to prove it when it is (2n+1)^3, and the final expression is a little bit different. I just need help factoring my last step.

Any corrections on the inductive steps that i followed are appreciated too.

Comment: Have you simply tried expanding both sides completely? You should end up with a 4th degree polynomial. It may be more tedious than a cleverer manipulation, but it is guaranteed to work.

Comment: I learnt that I can't just work with both sides because it may affect the result. If I do that is pretty easy to be honest, that's why im searching if it has any trick or something.

Comment: If you know $1^3+2^3+...+n^3=\left(\dfrac{n(n+1)}2\right)^2,\\ $ then $1^3+3^3+...+(2n+1)^3=1^3+2^3+...+(2n+1)^3-(2^3+4^3+...+(2n)^3)\\=\left(\dfrac{(2n+1)(2n+2)}2\right)^2-8\left(\dfrac{n(n+1)}2\right)^2=(2n+1)^2(n+1)^2-2n^2(n+1)^2=(n+1)^2[(2n+1)^2-2n^2]=(n+1)^2(2n^2+4n+1)$

Comment: your inductive steps look fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the factor $(k+2)^2$ by the following way.
$$(k+1)^2(2k^2+1)+(2k+3)^2=2k^4+16k^3+47k^2+60k+28=$$
$$=2k^4+8k^3+8k^2+8k^3+32k^2+32k+7k^2+28k+28=$$
$$=(k+2)^2(2k^2+8k+7)=(k+2)^2(2(k+1)^2+4(k+1)+1).$$

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the most elegant solution,

but $(k+1)^2(2k^2+4k+1) + (2k+3)^3= (k+2)^2 ( 2(k+1)^2 + 4(k+1) + 1)$

is true because both sides equal $2k^4+16k^3+47k^2+60k+28$.

Comment: Well, i learnt that i can't work with both sides of the equation because it can lead to some false statements, i know if i expand it's easy to see that it's true, but I didn't know that this was valid. After reading the comments i see that it may be correct.

Comment: somewhat less inelegant:  $(k+1)^2(2k^2+4k+1) + (2k+3)^3=[(k+2)^2-(2k+3)](2k^2+4k+1)+(2k+3)^3\\=(k+2)^2(2k^2+4k+1)+(2k+3)[(2k+3)^2-(2k^2+4k+1)]\\=(k+2)^2(2k^2+4k+1)+(2k+3)(4k^2+12k+9-2k^2-4k-1)\\=(k+2)^2(2k^2+4k+1)+(2k+3)(2k^2+8k+8)=(k+2)^2(2k^2+4k+1)+(2k+3)2(k+2)^2\\= (k+2)^2 ( 2k^2 + 4k+1+4k+6)=(k+2)^2(2k^2+8k+7)\\=  (k+2)^2(2(k+1)^2+4(k+1)+1)$

Comment: You could invite extraneous solutions if you, for example, square both sides of an equation (e.g., $x=y\implies x^2=y^2$, but $x^2=y^2\implies x=\pm y$), but simply expanding is okay

Comment: Ohh, okay. Thanks.